# OpenCV-KalmanFilter::predict() error

Tags: opencv, runtime-error, kalman-filter, predict

I'm trying to get an implementation of the Kalman Filter with on OpenCV, so I've followed the following example of tracking of rotating point (OpenCV 2.4.3):

http://fossies.org/unix/misc/OpenCV-2.4.3.tar.gz:a/OpenCV-2.4.3/samples/cpp/kalman.cpp

I am using OpenCV 2.4.2, and QtCreator 4.7.4. All compiles fine, but when I execute the program crashes at the end of this code:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    help();
    Mat img(500, 500, CV_8UC3);
    KalmanFilter KF(2, 1, 0);
    Mat state(2, 1, CV_32F); /* (phi, delta_phi) */
    Mat processNoise(2, 1, CV_32F);
    Mat measurement = Mat::zeros(1, 1, CV_32F);
    char code = (char)-1;

    for(;;)
    {
       randn( state, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(0.1) );
       KF.transitionMatrix = *(Mat_<float>(2, 2) << 1, 1, 0, 1);

       setIdentity(KF.measurementMatrix);
       setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-5));
       setIdentity(KF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-1));
       setIdentity(KF.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(1));

       randn(KF.statePost, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(0.1));

       for(;;)
       {
          Point2f center(img.cols*0.5f, img.rows*0.5f);
          float R = img.cols/3.f;
          double stateAngle = state.at<float>(0);
          Point statePt = calcPoint(center, R, stateAngle);

          Mat prediction = KF.predict(); //it crashes here
       ...
```

I also tried this tutorial (OpenCV 2.2), and it also crashed at the same point: the .predict() function:

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/06/17/simple-kalman-filter-for-tracking-using-opencv-2-2-w-code/comment-page-1/#comment-34618

QtCreator doesn't show me the error code, so I can't figure out what's going on here. I've checked other posts and they say that the problem may be that the matrixes aren't of the same size, but I doubt that since this example works for other people who tried it...

Anyone could give me a hint on how to solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: http://fossies.org/linux/misc/opencv-2.4.5.tar.gz:a/opencv-2.4.5/samples/cpp/kalman.cpp works fine for me. You can try to put a try/catch around it to see what goes wrong there.